# Bing Maps Windows Store 8.1 Show All Pins

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

The Bing Maps Control for Windows 8.1 universal runtime (I'm using Windows Phone) has a built in behavior of only showing pins with no overlap.  If you add 100 pins to the map, but any overlap each other, one of "touching" pins will be removed. You must zoom in until there is enough room to show both without them overlapping.  How do I turn off this behavior?  The map knows it has 100 pins as children, but it may only show a dozen or so due to the no-overlap logic.

I want to show all pins on the map, regardless if they overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only happens if you use MapIcon's. Instead, create pushpins using a UIElement and add it to the Children property of the map. This is a very common way to create custom pushpins in all of the Bing Maps controls (Silverlight, WPF, WP7/8/8.1, Win8/8.1/10).

Comment: Thanks Ricky, this is what I needed.